# Dependence of random variables.

Tags: probability, random-variables, independence, correlation

So I'm quite unsure how two random variables, $X, Y$ depend on each other. So if they are independent, their correlation equals $0$. But I'm curious if $\rho_{XY} = 0$, does it automatically imply that the two random variables are independent? And if it doesn't, could you give me an exact answer for me to understand it properly?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence

Comment: $\rho_{X,Y}= 0$ does not imply independence. This can happen just by coinsidence. What do you mean by "exact answer"?